# Session Timeout in web.xml not working for weblogic server

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic

I have set the timeout to 30 mins in web.xml and have successfully deployed the webapp in WebLogic. Now the app is up and running but when the max inactive interval reaches, the session doesn't timeout. This same app is timing out in tomcat properly.

Can anyone please suggest some idea?

Also I want to know whether there is an app specific weblogic.xml? If yes, then where do I find it?

Comment: Is there anyone who knows a correct solution to this?
I am yet to finish the issue.

Comment: I created a weblogic.xml file but the server won't allow me to deploy the app with the file. The server allows me to deploy without the weblogic.xml file but the session won't time out. Is there anyone who could help me with this timeout issue?

Comment: Just to clarify that you are migrating an application from Tomcat X to WebLogic Y without any changes in the code or configuration files probably won't deploy or will deploy with issues. Creating a proper weblogic.xml file is one of the issues you'll need to solve, along with migrating datasources. You should create a dummy WLS web app to understand the structure of folders.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options you have:

1. You can edit the File web.xml:
   Edit the session-timeout of the session-config in the file web.xml. Please note in web.xml, the session timeout is set in minutes.

   ```
   <session-config>
            <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   ```
2. You can edit the File weblogic.xml:
   Edit the session-param TimeoutSecs in the file weblogic.xml. In weblogic.xml, the session timeout is set in seconds.

   ```
    <session-descriptor>
          <session-param>
              <param-name>TimeoutSecs</param-name>
             <param-value>3600</param-value>
         </session-param>
    </session-descriptor>
   ```

Note that the timeout value set in web.xml takes precedence over weblogic.xml. If you don't set any values in web.xml, weblogic.xml takes over. A good approach to handle session timeout is setting this just on web.xml itself since web.xml takes precedence over application server’s deployment descriptors.

For more information refer to :
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13712/web_xml.htm#i1023849

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

well the session timeout setting in both web.xml and weblogic.xml should work. pls note that the unit in web.xml is minute, but in weblogic.xml is second.

And the timeout setting in web.xml takes precedence over weblogic.xml.

weblogic.xml should be under WEB-INF/

for session-descriptor in weblogic.xml:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1071982

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but I am unable to see any weblogic.xml in WEB-INF. There is only web.xml. Is it missing in my application? What should I do?

Comment: @Raghul you can create one. the link in my answer explains how should it look like. there are other example on inet too. but for the session timeout, web.xml should work as well.

Comment: Kent: Now I have a clear picture of how the weblogic.xml would look like, but will it already be in the Web-Inf/ dir or we should be the one to create it? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Raghul weblogic server has no idea what is your web-app, so it won't somehow generate a file for you when it starts. And the web-inf dir is a sub-directory of your web-app. just like you have created web.xml, you could create weblogic.xml as well, if you need.

Comment: I did create weblogic.xml but the server doesn't let me deploy the app, please help.