# JSF Web Application Timeout Issue

Tags: session, jsf, web.xml, weblogic12c, session-timeout

I have a web application built using JSF 2.2 and deployed on WebLogic 12.2.1.1.

I have set the session timeout in web.xml as 480 to keep it active for at least 8 hours.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        480
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

However, still my web application times out within 15 minutes when kept idle. My LoginSession JSF managed bean defined in session scope is getting re-initialized.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginsession")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginSession implements Serializable {

    private boolean userLoggedIn;

    public LoginSession() {
    }

    public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
        return userLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setUserLoggedIn(boolean userLoggedIn) {
        this.userLoggedIn = userLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

userLoggedIn variable in LoginSession is set to true once the user logs into the application.

However, after 15 minutes when LoginSession is injected into a ViewScoped bean, userLoggedIn is turning out to be false and redirects me to the error page.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "home")
@ViewScoped
public class Home {

    @ManagedProperty("#{loginsession}")
    private LoginSession loginSession;

    public Home() {
    }

    public void prepare() {
        try {
            if (!loginSession.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                Exception ex = new Exception("User Not Logged In. Please <span class=\"text-bold text-danger\"><a href=\"/WebUtil/faces/login/index.xhtml\" class=\"text-danger\">RE-LOGIN</a></span> .");
                Helper.redirectToErrorPage(ex, loginSession);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    public LoginSession getLoginSession() {
        return loginSession;
    }

    public void setLoginSession(LoginSession loginSession) {
        this.loginSession = loginSession;
    }

}
```

I am not able to figure out the issue. I appreciate if some one can provide me a hint of what is happening. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "login")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginPage {
    @ManagedProperty("#{loginsession}")
    private LoginSession loginSession;

    public void setLoginSession(LoginSession bea) {
        loginSession = bea;
    }

    public void prepare() {
        loginSession.setUserLoggedIn(false);
    }

    public String submit() {
        loginSession.setUserLoggedIn(true);
        return "/faces/floor/Home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

submit() method is executed when the user enters credentials and clicks log in. prepare() is executed when the login page loads.

Comment: Are you actually saying that if you don't use JSF, you don't have this problem?

Comment: How/where do you set it `true`?

Comment: please see my edits in the post above.

Comment: Looks ok to me so far. Didn't notice your edit because you didn't @SirishV me. A you sure the web.xml is actually affective at all? Regarding an older answer it shuld take precedence over a WEB-INF/weblogic.xml or weblogic defaults: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930703/session-timeout-in-web-xml-not-working-for-weblogic-server

Comment: @Selaron I believe if web.xml is not effective it should at least default the session timeout to 30 mins. This issue is somewhat inconsistent and I couldn't replicate it today even after the leaving the application idle in the backgroung for more than 60 mins. I don't have a weblogic.xml file and my weblogic server timeout is set to 60 mins by default.

Comment: Like mentioned above. Check with a simple plain jsp or servlet 99.9% certain it is **not JSF related**

Comment: May be it is not JSF related. I am guessing this could be a clustering issue on the load balancer... still trying to figure it out.

Comment: If it's not application related, with constant 15 minute timeouts I would hint towards network related; a firewall rule perhaps. Taking clustering in consideration, can you check if it only exists on one or all nodes in the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is now resolved. It was an issue with load balancer redirecting to a different server after certain period of inactivity.